# Yii updateAll() add 1 to current value of row

Tags: php, yii

Simply said, I am trying to do this:

```
$widgetsUsed->updateAll(array(
                'position'=>'- 1'
            ),
            "position > {$position} AND sidebar_id = {$sidebar_id}"
         );
```

Does anyone have a clue if this works, or give some other suggestions how to achieve this?

Having a hard time to debug this since I can't exactly make up what values are chaning when in my database. So I was hoping anyone here would directly know how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which yii version are you using ? 1.1.8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as below

```
Yii::app()->db->commandBuilder->createUpdateCounterCommand('{{myTable}}', array(
  'position' => 1, // -1 for decrementing
  new CDbCriteria(array(
        "condition" => "position > :pos AND sidebar_id = :id",
        "params" => array(
            "pos"=>$position, 
            "id"=>$sidebar_id
        )
    ))
));
```

If you have `higher version of Yii`, then you can use http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/282/using-counters-with-activerecord/

Comment: The updatecounters thing is great, the code you provided is way too much for a simple action like this.